# how to store critical data on PaymentRequest API

Tags: google-chrome, security, payment, payment-request-api

I'm using payment request API, first thing i ask the user to sign-in and enroll, then i give him a token, this token is a very critical data for my payment method, i want to store in just like the  card number and cvc.
Im asking if there is a way to store this token securely - preferably natively - and to be used each time the user choose to pay with my payment method.